# Capture Image from Secondary Monitor, cropping, and saving

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to write an application that takes a screen shot of an area on one of the monitors and saves it to an image.  The Screen shot should be taken at a x,y coordinate with a given width and height.  When the image saves it should be saved at 0,0 and the same width height.  I have this working on my main monitor but when I attempt to take the screen shot of my 2nd or 3rd monitor it doesnt work.  I either get a black image or a file that when opened says its an invalid format.

My code is a modified version of the following code that takes a screen shot of the entire desktop.
https://github.com/GERD0GDU/dxgi_desktop_capture

Main Monitor width/height
2560 X 1440

Main monitor top corner x/y coordinates are 0,0 retrieved by calling

```
    POINT cursorPos;
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
```

Secondary Monitor width/height
1080 x 1920

Secondary monitor top corner x/y coordinates are 2560,-238

For reference for my image coordinates that work on the main monitor i'm passing in x:801 y:227, width:1756, height:1115

For my 2nd monitor which sits to the right of my main monitor and is flipped sideways making it taller than wide I'm passing in x:2907 y:-11 width:737 height:1595

```
    HRESULT CDXGICapture::CaptureToFile(_In_ LPCWSTR lpcwOutputFileName, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    AUTOLOCK();

    if (!m_bInitialized) {
        return D2DERR_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }

    CHECK_POINTER_EX(m_ipDxgiOutputDuplication, E_INVALIDARG);
    CHECK_POINTER_EX(lpcwOutputFileName, E_INVALIDARG);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = DXGICaptureHelper::IsRendererInfoValid(&m_rendererInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    // is valid?
    hr = DXGICaptureHelper::GetContainerFormatByFileName(lpcwOutputFileName);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO     FrameInfo;
    CComPtr<IDXGIResource>      ipDesktopResource;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>    ipAcquiredDesktopImage;
    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap>        ipD2D1SourceBitmap;

    

    // Get new frame

    int lTryCount = 4;

    do
    {
        Sleep(1);

        hr = m_ipDxgiOutputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(250, &FrameInfo, &ipDesktopResource);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;

        if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (FAILED(hr))
            break;

    } while (--lTryCount > 0);

    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    else if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // QI for ID3D11Texture2D
    hr = ipDesktopResource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&ipAcquiredDesktopImage));
    ipDesktopResource = nullptr;
    CHECK_HR_RETURN(hr);

    if (nullptr == ipAcquiredDesktopImage)
    {
        // release frame
        m_ipDxgiOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }

    // Copy needed full part of desktop image
    m_ipD3D11DeviceContext->CopyResource(m_ipCopyTexture2D, ipAcquiredDesktopImage);

    // release frame
    hr = m_ipDxgiOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();
    CHECK_HR_RETURN(hr);
    

    // create D2D1 source bitmap
    hr = DXGICaptureHelper::CreateBitmap(m_ipD2D1RenderTarget, m_ipCopyTexture2D, &ipD2D1SourceBitmap);
    CHECK_HR_RETURN(hr);

    //try this
    D2D1_RECT_F rcSource = D2D1::RectF(
        (FLOAT)x,
        (FLOAT)y,
        (FLOAT)x + width,
        (FLOAT)y+ height);
    
    D2D1_RECT_F rcTarget = D2D1::RectF(
        (FLOAT)0,
        (FLOAT)0,
        (FLOAT)width,
        (FLOAT)height);
        
    D2D1_POINT_2F ptTransformCenter = D2D1::Point2F(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f);

    // Apply the rotation transform to the render target.
    D2D1::Matrix3x2F rotate = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(
        m_rendererInfo.RotationDegrees,
        ptTransformCenter
    );

    D2D1::Matrix3x2F scale = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(
        D2D1::SizeF(1, 1),
        ptTransformCenter
    );

    // Priority: first rotate, after scale...
    m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->SetTransform(rotate * scale);

    m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->BeginDraw();
    // clear background color
    m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White, 1.0f));
    m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->DrawBitmap(ipD2D1SourceBitmap, rcTarget, 1.0f, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, rcSource);

    //m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
    hr = m_ipD2D1RenderTarget->EndDraw();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    hr = DXGICaptureHelper::SaveImageToFile(m_ipWICImageFactory, m_ipWICOutputBitmap, lpcwOutputFileName, width, height);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    return S_OK;
} // CaptureToFile
```

My save to file method

```
static
    COM_DECLSPEC_NOTHROW
    inline
    HRESULT
    SaveImageToFile(
        _In_ IWICImagingFactory* pWICImagingFactory,
        _In_ IWICBitmapSource* pWICBitmapSource,
        _In_ LPCWSTR lpcwFileName,
        _In_ unsigned int uiWidth,
        _In_ unsigned int uiHeight
    )
{
    CHECK_POINTER_EX(pWICImagingFactory, E_INVALIDARG);
    CHECK_POINTER_EX(pWICBitmapSource, E_INVALIDARG);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    GUID guidContainerFormat;

    hr = GetContainerFormatByFileName(lpcwFileName, &guidContainerFormat);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    WICPixelFormatGUID format = GUID_WICPixelFormatDontCare;
    CComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> ipWICImagingFactory(pWICImagingFactory);
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapSource> ipWICBitmapSource(pWICBitmapSource);
    CComPtr<IWICStream> ipStream;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> ipEncoder;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> ipFrameEncode;
//  unsigned int uiWidth = 1756;
//  unsigned int uiHeight = 1115;

    hr = ipWICImagingFactory->CreateStream(&ipStream);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = ipStream->InitializeFromFilename(lpcwFileName, GENERIC_WRITE);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = ipWICImagingFactory->CreateEncoder(guidContainerFormat, NULL, &ipEncoder);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipEncoder->Initialize(ipStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&ipFrameEncode, NULL);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipFrameEncode->Initialize(NULL);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipFrameEncode->SetSize(uiWidth, uiHeight);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipFrameEncode->SetPixelFormat(&format);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipFrameEncode->WriteSource(ipWICBitmapSource, NULL);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipFrameEncode->Commit();
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ipEncoder->Commit();
    }

    return hr;
} // SaveImageToFile
```

Comment: Figured out the issue was the coordinates I pass in need to always be relative the monitor by itself and not the collective. Once i normalized the coordinates the screen shots take correctly.  Will note that it only works when the screen orientation is Landscape.  When i flip the monitor to Portrait the screen shot is off.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates being passed in needed to be normalized to the monitor by itself without considering the other monitors. IE all x and y values needed to be positive from a 0,0 being the top left of the monitor.

To get the coordinates for a monitor I used the following where the Control is the view I was trying to capture within my application.

```
Monitor[] monitors = Display.getDefault().getMonitors();
    Control control = getScreenCaptureControlArea();
    Point p = control.toDisplay(0, 0);
    for (Monitor monitor : monitors) {
        Rectangle bounds = monitor.getBounds();
        if (monitor.getBounds().contains(p.x, p.y)) {
        setxCord(Math.abs(Math.abs(bounds.x) - Math.abs(p.x)));
        setyCord(Math.abs(Math.abs(bounds.y) - Math.abs(p.y)));
        setWidth(control.getSize().x);
        setHeight(control.getSize().y);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Will note that this still doesnt work when the monitor is in Portrait mode as the image saved is incorrect. But seeing as my application isnt meant to be used in a Portrait mode it didnt matter much so i didnt put any more effort into figuring out that problem.